# Countif function in R

Tags: r, countif

I have  a matrix of n*m dimension. I wanted to count the  number of columns in a row which has a value greater than "X". How to do this in R?  Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `rowSums`

```
 X <- 0.5
 rowSums(m1 > X)
```

#### explanation

`m1 > X` will create a `TRUE`/`FALSE` logical matrix. Since `TRUE` values are treated as `1` and `FALSE` values are treated as `0`, `rowSums(m1 > X)` will give you a count for each row of the number of values in that row that is greater than `X`.

#### data

```
 set.seed(24)
 m1 <- matrix(rnorm(5*10), ncol=5)
```

Comment: rowSums sumup the rows and compare with the cutoff value. I would like to count how many entires in a row is greater than the cutoff value.

Comment: @satty That is what it does.  It compares with the cutoff values to get a `TRUE/FALSE` logical matrix and we sum the `TRUE` values to get the count of values greater than cutoff values.  Also, please check the code.  `rowSums(m1)` and `rowSums(m1 >X)` are different